# JQuery and Knockout not working together

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a problem with binding of JQuery and Knockout!

I don't know where my problem is! Maybe anyone of you could take a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ed98/1/)

This is how I try to go to the next Knockout ViewModel:

```
  masterViewModel.loginVM(null);
  masterViewModel.startVM(new StartVM());
```

That's my MasterViewModel

```
 var masterViewModel = {

            loginVM: ko.observable(),
            startVM: ko.observable(),
        };
```

if JQuery mobile is not used (bind into my ASP.NET MVC4 project) it works fine

Here is the same fiddle, just that jQuery is not used: [fiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/B2A5f/)

When I try this in ASP.NET MVC4 it doesn't work right!

```
<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }"> 
 //SomeCode
</form>

<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': startVM, data: startVM}"> 
//Some Code
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var masterViewModel = {

            loginVM: ko.observable(),
            startVM: ko.observable(),
            projektUnterbrechen: ko.observable(),
            logout : ko.observable(),
            projectStartVM: ko.observable()

        };

        var LoginVM = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.mandant = ko.observable();
            self.user = ko.observable();
            self.password = ko.observable();
            self.showDetails = function () {
                if ((self.user() == "Gregor") && (self.password() == "gregrech")) {
                    masterViewModel.loginVM(null);
                    masterViewModel.startVM(new StartVM());


                }
                else {
                    alert("Username oder Passwort falsch");
                }

            };
        };

        var StartVM = function () {
            self = this;
            //Um weiterzumachen muss man eingeloggt sein
            self.favoriten = ko.observableArray([
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit1"
                },
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit2"
                },
                {
                    projectName: "Favorit3"
                }
                ]);
            //Die zuletzt verwendeten Projekte
            self.zuletzt = ko.observableArray([
            {
                lastProjName: "Zuletzt1"
            },
            {
                lastProjName: "Zuletzt2"
            },
            {
                lastProjName: "Zuletzt3"
            }
            ]);
            self.showStart = function (projectName, data, event) {
                masterViewModel.projectStartVM(new ProjectStartVM(projectName));
                masterViewModel.startVM(null);
            };
        };
        masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM());
        $(document).on('pageinit', function () {
            ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);
        });

</script>
```

Comment: your jsFiddle doesn't work :)

Comment: i added a second jsFiddle to my question so you can see what i mean ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding:

```
<form action="" data-bind="template: { 'if': startVM, data: startVM } ">

<form action="" data-bind=" template:{ 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM }">
```

Like this, try:

```
<form action="" data-bind="css: { hidden: startVM==null } ">

<form action="" data-bind="css: { hidden: loginVM ==null } ">
```

And of course hidden in CSS would be:

```
.hidden{ display:none; }
```

That is the status quo way of showing one thing or another with knockout.

After seeing your second fiddle I checked what version of knockout you are using - it's 1.2.0. So, what I did is upgrade your fiddle with 2.2.0 http://jsfiddle.net/2Ed98/2/ and it works as expected. Knockout had problems with compatibility around version 1.

Comment: it shouldn't only be hidden, but loaded new..

but thank you! I'll try this in my fiddle

Comment: well, basically you control what you load elsewhere with setting the values to the observables, but basically if the value is not null, you show it and else you don't. Or maybe I got you wrong, so please add more details :)

Comment: that's pretty much what i do!
But the hiding is not the problem..

My problem is, that everything works fine if there is no JQuery. Maybe i don't bind knockout correctly, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong
I added a second fiddle to my question. Maybe you understand what i mean after you looked at this one.

Comment: I've updated the answer :) check managed resources tab in jsFiddle

Comment: Thank you!

I tried to use this in my mvc application. The binding seems to work as the messagebox appers, but the "StartVM" is not loaded
you got an idea what's the problem with this one? ;)

Comment: well if I set the username to Gregor and password gregrech, the other view displays ok

Comment: it should at least!

As i said the new Model is loaded and the messagebox from "StartVM" is loaded, but the UI is not shown

Comment: I'm not quiet sure if you get me right...

The fiddle you postet was perfectly fine!

As i use ASP.NET MVC4 i copied and pastet the code, but somehow it doesn't work there.

There has to be a problem with JQuery mobile. 
As i said the Messagebox is displayed, but the User-Interface is not updatet, which means after i Log-in i get the Messagebox from the StartVM (which you commented) and then the page is empty. In your Fiddle it works as we have alredy seen. Maybe i have to use a $(function(){ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel)}); but that doesn't change anything

Comment: do you now understand what i mean?

Comment: well you should check javascript console for errors, maybe you haven't switched the knockout version there yet?

Comment: the knockout version is 2.2.0

Comment: i edited the question so you can see how i tried to bind the ViewModel to the view